# Using Regexp_substr to display specific text

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column called keys with data in this format:

> qwert! B1 12345! B3 abcde! B4 fgh14777
>   stat! B3 3456! C0 224466! B2 bbmm

I'm trying to use regexp_substr to display only text that starts with B3 and end with a character before the next exclamation mark (!)
So my desired result would be this:
B3 abcde
B3 3456

B3 might be be on any position within the string and the length of the text might vary as well. Not every row contains B3.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what regex have you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly, nothing worth mentioning. I didn't use this function before and even though I spend time reading manual I can't figure it out.

Comment: i made this regex `B3.{0,}?!` tested here https://regex101.com/r/bo61pP/1

Comment: It shows the ! in the end, but I think I can change it myself. Thank you!

Comment: did you not want the !?

Comment: Nope, I want the final result to look like this: B3 abcde

Comment: then gordons regex is better than mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty simple regular expression:

```
select regexp_substr('qwert! B1 12345! B3 abcde! B4 fgh14777', 'B3[^!]+', 1, 1)
from dual
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon!